# Character frequency histogram in C

Tags: c, character, histogram

I read this program, but i'm not able to understand it. Please explain what exactly is happening  in the `length[]` arraay . How can it be used to store different type of characters i.e. both digits & chars.Following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define EOL '\n'
#define ARYLEN 256
main()
{
    int c, i, x;
    int length[ARYLEN];
    for(x = 0; x < ARYLEN;x++)
        length[x] = 0;
    while( (c = getchar() ) != EOL)
     {
        length[c]++;
    if (c == EOL)
        break;
    }    
    for(x = 0; x < ARYLEN; x++)
    {
         if( length[x] > 0){
            printf("%c | ", x);
            for(i = 1; i <= length[x]; ++i){
                printf("*");
         }
         printf("\n");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array doesn't store any characters (at least conceptually). It stores the number of times the program has encountered a character with the numerical value `c` in the array position of index `c`.

Basically, in the C programming language, a `char` is a datatype that consists of 8 bits and is able to hold values of the range 0 to 255 for an `unsigned char` or -128 to 127 for a `signed char`.
The program then defines an array large enough to hold as many different values as it is possible to represent using a `char`, one array position for each unique value.
Then it counts the number of occurances using the appropriate array position, `length[c]`, as a counter for that specific value. As it loops over the array to print out the data, it can tell which character the data belongs to just by looking at the current index inside the loop, so `printf("%c | ", x);` is the character while `length[x]` is the data we're after.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the integer array `length[]` is not used to store characters. It is only used to store the count of each character being typed. The characters are read one by one into the character variable `c` `while( (c = getchar() ) != EOL)`.

But the tricky part is `length[c]++;`. The count of each character is kept at a location equal to its `ASCII value - 1` in the array `length[]`.

For example in a system using `ASCII` codes, `length[64]` contains the count of `A`, because `65` is the `ASCII` code for `A`.

`length[65]` contains the count of `B`, because `66` is the `ASCII-8` code for `B`.

`length[96]` contains the count of `a`, because `97` is the `ASCII` code for `a`.

`length[47]` contains the count of `0`, because `48` is the `ASCII` code for `0`.

Comment: ASCII ends at 127 (decimal). It is not known, and unnecessary to know, which character code is in use.